# Handshake between JS WebSocket and Java

Tags: javascript, java, websocket, http-headers, java-websocket

I tried to implement the WebSocket Protocol and connecting a JavaScript WebSocket with a Java WebSocket Server.

The JavaScript part is pretty straight forward and works as expected.
I wrote the Java server myself and read the [rfc 6455 page 7](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#page-7) for the correct handshake response. So the server generates the correct response and sends it. I wrote a Java client dummy to make sure it gets send.

But the problem is that the JavaScript / Browser seems not to receive the handshake response and kills the request after some seconds (but does not close the tcp socket).

Here is the handshake:

Client

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:4455
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Origin: http://localhost
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate
Sec-WebSocket-Key: dGhlIHNhbXBsZSBub25jZQ==
Connection: keep-alive, Upgrade
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Upgrade: websocket
```

Server

```
HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: s3pPLMBiTxaQ9kYGzzhZRbK+xOo=
Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: chat
```

HTML JavaScript

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Socket testing - Client</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            var socket = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:4455');

            socket.addEventListener("error",function(e){
                console.log("an error ocurred: ",e)
            })
            socket.addEventListener("close",function(e){
                console.log("the connection was closed: ",e)
            })
            socket.addEventListener("open",function(e){
                console.log("the connection was opened: ",e)
            })
            socket.addEventListener("message",function(e){
                console.log("recieved a message: ",e)
            })

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Java (excerpt)

```
public class SocketHandlerWebSocketLevel extends SocketHandler {

    private HashMap<String, String> connectionHeaders;
    private InputStreamReader stringReader;
    private OutputStreamWriter stringWriter;

    public SocketHandlerWebSocketLevel(Socket socket) {
        super(socket);
        connectionHeaders = new HashMap<String, String>();

        try {
            stringReader = new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            close();
            print("could not get the input stream");
            return;
        }

        try {
            stringWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            close();
            print("could not get the output stream");
            return;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        print("Started handler");
        char b;
        String buffer = "";
        try {
            mainLoop: while (true) {
                while (stringReader.ready() || buffer.length() == 0) {
                    if ((b = (char) stringReader.read()) != -1) {
                        buffer += b;
                    } else {
                        break mainLoop;
                    }

                }
                gotMessage(buffer);
                buffer = "";
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            close();
            print("connection was killed remotly, could not read the next byte");
            return;
        }

        close();
        print("connection was closed remotely, stopped Handler, closed socked");
    }

    private void gotMessage(String message) {
        if (connectionHeaders.size() == 0) {
            connectionHeaders = parseHttpHeader(message);
            handshakeResponse();
        } else {
            print(message);
        }
    }

    private void handshakeResponse() {
        /* 
           taken from: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#page-7
           For this header field, the server has to take the value (as present
           in the header field, e.g., the base64-encoded [RFC4648] version minus
           any leading and trailing whitespace) and concatenate this with the
           Globally Unique Identifier (GUID, [RFC4122]) "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-
           95CA-C5AB0DC85B11" in string form, which is unlikely to be used by
           network endpoints that do not understand the WebSocket Protocol.  A
           SHA-1 hash (160 bits) [FIPS.180-3], base64-encoded (see Section 4 of
           [RFC4648]), of this concatenation is then returned in the server's
           handshake.
        
           Concretely, if as in the example above, the |Sec-WebSocket-Key|
           header field had the value "dGhlIHNhbXBsZSBub25jZQ==", the server
           would concatenate the string "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11"
           to form the string "dGhlIHNhbXBsZSBub25jZQ==258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-
           C5AB0DC85B11".  The server would then take the SHA-1 hash of this,
           giving the value 0xb3 0x7a 0x4f 0x2c 0xc0 0x62 0x4f 0x16 0x90 0xf6
           0x46 0x06 0xcf 0x38 0x59 0x45 0xb2 0xbe 0xc4 0xea.  This value is
           then base64-encoded (see Section 4 of [RFC4648]), to give the value
           "s3pPLMBiTxaQ9kYGzzhZRbK+xOo=".  This value would then be echoed in
           the |Sec-WebSocket-Accept| header field.
        */

        String secWebSocketKey, secWebSocketAccept, GUID, template, merged, toSend;
        secWebSocketKey = connectionHeaders.get("Sec-WebSocket-Key");
        GUID = "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11";
        template = "HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols\nUpgrade: websocket\nConnection: Upgrade\nSec-WebSocket-Accept: %s\nSec-WebSocket-Protocol: chat\n";

        // combine secWebSocketKey and the GUID
        merged = secWebSocketKey + GUID;
        print("merged: " + merged);

        // convert to byte[]
        byte[] asBytes = merged.getBytes();
        print("asBytes: " + Arrays.toString(asBytes));

        // SHA-1 hash
        byte[] sha1 = SHA1Hash(asBytes);
        print("sha1: " + Arrays.toString(sha1));

        // base64 encode
        byte[] base64 = base64Encode(sha1);
        print("base64: " + Arrays.toString(base64));

        // reconvert to string to put it into the template
        secWebSocketAccept = new String(base64);

        toSend = String.format(template, secWebSocketAccept);
        print(toSend);

        try {
            stringWriter.write(toSend, 0, toSend.length());
            stringWriter.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            print("hanshake sending failed!");
        }

    }

    private HashMap<String, String> parseHttpHeader(String h) {
        HashMap<String, String> fields = new HashMap<String, String>();

        String[] rows = h.split("\n");
        if (rows.length > 1) {
            fields.put("Prototcol", rows[0]);
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^([^:]+): (.+)$");
            for (int i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
                Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(rows[i]);
                while (matcher.find()) {
                    if (matcher.groupCount() == 2) {
                        fields.put(matcher.group(1), matcher.group(2));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return fields;
    }

    private byte[] SHA1Hash(byte[] bytes) {
        MessageDigest md;

        try {
            md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            return null;
        }

        md.update(bytes);
        return md.digest();
    }

    private byte[] base64Encode(byte[] bytes) {
        byte[] encodedBytes = Base64.getEncoder().encode(bytes);
        return encodedBytes;
    }
```

Where might be my error? What could be missing, maybe a "message end" symbol?

Note that I don't want to use a framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was simple. I just used Wireshark to debug this whole thing: I just forgot the carriage return.

The correct string in the Java class would be:

```
template = "HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols\r\nUpgrade: websocket\r\nConnection: Upgrade\r\nSec-WebSocket-Accept: %s\r\nSec-WebSocket-Protocol: chat\r\n\r\n";
```

Until this modification the browser is not able to interpret it as HTTP data in the TCP package.

Comment: I've just noticed you've undone one of my edits, in which I trimmed some chatty material. I would suggest [this community discussion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/295810/472495) is relevant. If you're a new user I would recommend reading the _Meta_ site generally, to understand some of the ways in which community editing works, which often includes the trimming of any material that is not germane to a question or answer. I am also open to discussing my own editing rationale if you wish.

Comment: @halfer sorry I was just happy about the good support Wireshark has, so this debugging was possible. I will remove it.